Stuck on last step of reducing to canonical form of $u_{xx} + x^2u_{yy} = 0$
I have most of the question done but I've no idea how to get the last step. The correct final answer is supposed to be
$$ u_{\lambda\lambda} + u_{\sigma\sigma} = -\frac{u_\lambda}{2\lambda}  $$
I saw that it's an elliptical equation. What I have done is gotten the pair of complex solutions as
$$ C_{*} = \frac{x^2}{2} \pm iy $$
I used these two conjugates as my substitution of variables $\eta$ and $\xi$.
From my notes I then saw I had to do a second change of variables to have the canonical form in terms of real co ordinates λ and σ so I did this step:
$$ \lambda = \frac{\eta+\xi}{2},\quad \sigma = i\frac{\eta-\xi}{2} $$
Giving
$$ \lambda = \frac{x^2}{2},\quad   \sigma = y $$
From here I put these new variables into the original PDE trying to solve for $u_{xx}$ and $x^2u_{yy}$ and I got
$$ 4\lambda u_{\lambda\lambda}+\lambda u_{\sigma\sigma}=0 $$
I know I have the right variables picked but I don't know how to put it in canonical form and have the third needed part of the equation. Any help would be appreciated.

You probably made a mistake when expressing the PDE in terms of $\lambda=\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $\sigma=y$. Using the chain rule, we have
\begin{align}
u_{x}&=u_{\lambda}\lambda_x+u_{\sigma}\sigma_x=xu_{\lambda}
=\sqrt{2\lambda}u_{\lambda}, \tag{1.1} \\
u_{y}&=u_{\lambda}\lambda_y+u_{\sigma}\sigma_y=u_{\sigma}, \tag{1.2} \\
u_{xx}&=(\sqrt{2\lambda}u_{\lambda})_{\lambda}\lambda_x+(\sqrt{2\lambda}u_{\lambda})_{\sigma}\sigma_x=\left(\sqrt{2\lambda}u_{\lambda\lambda}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\lambda}}u_\lambda\right)x \\
&=\left(\sqrt{2\lambda}u_{\lambda\lambda}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\lambda}}u_\lambda\right)\sqrt{2\lambda}=2\lambda u_{\lambda\lambda}+u_{\lambda}, \tag{1.3} \\
u_{yy}&=u_{\sigma\lambda}\lambda_y+u_{\sigma\sigma}\sigma_y=u_{\sigma\sigma}. \tag{1.4}
\end{align}
Plugging $(1.3)$ and $(1.4)$ into the PDE, we get
$$
2\lambda u_{\lambda\lambda}+u_{\lambda}+2\lambda u_{\sigma\sigma}=0 \implies
u_{\lambda\lambda}+u_{\sigma\sigma}+\frac{1}{2\lambda}u_{\lambda}=0. \tag{2}
$$

Thank you very much for that, that's the mistake I've been making with all these canonical form questions I see now, I was messing up the second differential with chain rule because of the changing variables
